# complex analysis definite integral

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Evaluate:

$$ \int_0 ^{+\infty} \frac {x^{a-1} dx} {1+x^3} $$ for $0 < a < 3$.

In the other problems in this section, we try to extend the bounds of the integral to $-\infty, +\infty$ so that it's a closed curve and we can solve for the residues.

However, I don't think we can do that here since it's not an even function.

the "$a$" in the numerator is giving me some problems.

Comment: Have you tried a wedge contour? Take a look at this for inspiration: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393875/contour-integral-int-infty-01zn-1dz

Comment: hm don't think we've learned that strategy yet. (I'm at section 4.3 of Marsden's basic complex analysis)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is that I will evaluate the more general integral

\begin{align*}
I_{a,n} = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x^n} \mathrm{d}x
= \frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty \frac{u^{a/n-1}}{1+u}\mathrm{d}u
\end{align*}
with $u \mapsto x^n$. I actually evaluated the last integral in my soon to be published master thesis about Hankel forms and Dirichlet series.

The last integral is the same as the Mellin transform of $f(x) = 1/(1+x)$ that is
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{M}_f(s) = \int_0^{\infty} x^{s-1} f(x) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi s}
\end{align*}
We will compute this Mellin transform using complex analysis, and then you can use the first line to obtain the value of your integral. Consider the branch of $z^{s-1}/(z+1)$ defined on the slit plane $C\backslash[0,\infty)$ by

\begin{align*}
    f(z) = \frac{r^{s-1}e^{i(s-1)\theta} }{z+1}\,,
\end{align*}

where $z = re^{i\theta}$, and $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$. For small $\varepsilon$ and $R > 1$, we consider the keyhole domain $C$,

[image]

consisting of $z$ in the slit plane $\mathbb{C}\backslash[0,\infty)$ satisfying $\varepsilon < |z| < R$, see the figure above. Since $f$ has a simple pole at $ =-1$, Cauchy's residue theorem yields

\begin{align}
    \int_C f(z) = 2\pi i \operatorname{Res}\limits_{z = -1}f(z) = -2\pi i e^{\pi i s}\,. \tag{0}
\end{align}

The integral over $C$ breaks into the sum of $4$ integrals.

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
      \int_{C} f(z) \mathrm{d}z
    & = \int_{\varepsilon}^R \frac{x^{s-1}}{x+1} \mathrm{d}x 
      + \int_{C_R} \frac{z^{s-1}}{z+1} \mathrm{d}z \\
    & + \int_R^{\varepsilon} \frac{e^{2\pi i(s-1)}x^{s-1}}{1+x} \mathrm{d}x 
      + \int_{C_\varepsilon} \frac{z^{s-1}}{z+1} \mathrm{d}z \,,
\end{split}
\tag{1}
\end{align}

and for the integrals over $C_R$ and $C_\varepsilon$ we obtain the following estimates

\begin{align}
        \left| 
            \int_{C_R} \frac{z^{s-1}}{z+1} \mathrm{d}z 
        \right| 
    & \leq \frac{R^{s-1}}{R-1} 2\pi R = O(R^{s}) \,, \tag{2} \\
        \left| 
            \int_{C_\varepsilon} \frac{z^{s-1}}{z+1} \mathrm{d}z\,.
        \right| 
    & \leq \frac{\varepsilon^{s-1}}{1 - \varepsilon} 2\pi \varepsilon = O(\varepsilon^s) \tag{3}
\end{align}

Letting $R \to \infty$ and $\varepsilon \to 0$ we see that ($2$) and ($3$) vanishes. That is since it is assumed that $0 < s < 1$ in order to assure that the Mellin transform converges. Thus for $\varepsilon \to 0$ and $R \to \infty$ equation ($1$) becomes

\begin{align*}
    \Bigl( 1 - e^{2\pi i(s-1)}\Bigr)\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{x+1} \mathrm{d}x 
    = -2\pi i e^{\pi i s}\,,
\end{align*}

where equation ($0$) was also applied. Thus,

\begin{align*}
      \mathcal{M}_g(s) 
    = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{1+x} \mathrm{d}x 
    = \pi \frac{2i}{e^{\pi i s-2\pi i} - e^{-\pi i s}} 
    = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)}\,,
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

It is more practical to use the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis). For any $a\in(0,3)$ the given integral is convergent and equals (by substituting $x=z^{1/3}$)
$$ \frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{+\infty}z^{\frac{a}{3}}\frac{dz}{z(z+1)}=\frac{1}{3}\Gamma\left(1+\frac{a}{3}\right)\int_{0}^{+\infty}s^{-1-\frac{a}{3}}(1-e^{-s})\,ds =\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{3 \sin\frac{\pi a}{3}}}$$
by the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: Can you add some more details from the first to the second line? How exactly are you taking the Laplace transform of the integral.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: I am simply exploiting $$\mathcal{L}(z^{a/3}) = s^{-1-a/3}\Gamma\left(1+\frac{a}{3}\right)$$ and $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{z(z+1)}\right)=1-e^{-s}.$$

Comment: Together with $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(z)\,g(z)\,dz = \int_{0}^{+\infty}(\mathcal{L}f)(s)\,(\mathcal{L}^{-1}g)(s)\,ds.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{a - 1} \over x^{3} + 1}\,\dd x & =
{1 \over 3}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{a/3 - 1} \over x + 1}\,\dd x =
{1 \over 3}\int_{1}^{\infty}{\pars{x - 1}^{a/3 - 1} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 3}\int_{1}^{0}{\pars{1/x - 1}^{a/3 - 1} \over 1/x}
\,\pars{-\,{1 \over x^{2}}}\dd x =
{1 \over 3}\int_{0}^{1}x^{-a/3}\pars{1 - x}^{a/3 - 1}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 3}\,{\Gamma\pars{1 - a/3}\Gamma\pars{a/3} \over \Gamma\pars{1}} =
{1 \over 3}\,{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi a/3}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\ds{{1 \over 3}\,\pi\csc\pars{{\pi \over 3}\,a}}}\,,\qquad
\Re\pars{a} \in \pars{0,3}
\end{align}