# Contour integral of an odd function

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am trying to calculate $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{1 + x^{2n}}
{\rm d}x$, $n$ being a positive integer greater than $2$:

- I already got the case where $n$ is $even$ and I am unsure what contour I should use when $n$ is $odd$.
- I tried calculating numerically a few cases and it seems that the formula I got for $n$ $even$ also applies to $n$ $odd$, so maybe there is some reasoning where I do not have to redo the integral again $?$.

Comment: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: What contour did you use when $n$ is even?

Comment: I used upper half circle for n even. But for $n$ odd the integrand would be an odd function.

Comment: Without doing any work myself, have you tried, say, a quarter circle with the imaginary axis?

Comment: I get it, and it makes sense, but for expressions with denominator $\frac 1{1+x^k}$ for some $k$, I'm left thinking about the wedge contour , which is basically a contour that would go around exactly one pole of the denominator. See e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393875/contour-integral-int-infty-01zn-1dz) for details.

Comment: In fact, this is probably a duplicate, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44928/interesting-integral-formula) for some details. The contour details from the answer are missing, but you can see the links and try to reconstruct the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have not seen this contour before. It seems to work for even n as well and the residue is far easier to compute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Too long for a comment*

Let's consider a general case:
$$I(m,k)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m}}{1 + x^k}dx; \,\,m\in (-1;k-2)$$
Then $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{1 + x^{2n}}dx=I(n,2n)$$

I would recommend to make substitution in the integral first:
$$I(m,k)= (t=x^k)\,\,\frac{1}{k}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{\frac{m+1}{k}-1}}{1+t}dt$$
Then we can easily evaluate the integral via Beta function, or using complex integration:
$$I(m,k)= (x=\frac{1}{1+t})\,\,\frac{1}{k}\int_0^1 x^{-\frac{m+1}{k}}(1-x)^{\frac{m+1}{k}-1}dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{k}B\Big(1-\frac{m+1}{k};\frac{m+1}{k}\Big)=\frac{\Gamma(1-\frac{m+1}{k})\Gamma(\frac{m+1}{k})}{k}=\frac{\pi}{k}\,\frac{1}{\sin\frac{\pi(m+1)}{k}}$$
$$I(n;2n)=\frac{\pi}{2n}\frac{1}{\sin\frac{\pi(n+1)}{2n}}=\frac{\pi}{2n}\frac{1}{\cos\frac{\pi}{2n}}$$

If we want to use the complex integration to evaluate $I(m,k)$, we can integrate along the keyhole contour with the cut $[0;\infty]$:

[image]

Let's denote $a=\frac{m+1}{k}-1\,\, (a<0)$, then
$$\frac{1}{k}\oint\frac{z^a}{1+z}dz=I(m,k)-e^{2\pi ia}I(m,k)=2\pi iRes_{z=e^{\pi i}}\frac{1}{k}\frac{z^a}{1+z}$$
$$I(m,k)=-\frac{\pi}{k}\frac{1}{\sin \pi a}=\frac{\pi}{k}\,\frac{1}{\sin\frac{\pi(m+1)}{k}}$$